# smartsheet C# SDK writing to empty cell seems not work

Tags: smartsheet-api

Using the smartsheet C# SDK i have written a method setCellValue to write a value to a cell given the row index, the column index and the value. The method works fine when there is already a value in the cell but it does not work when the cell is empty.

```
public void setCellValue(int rowIndex, int columnIndex, String value, Boolean setCellDisplayValue = true)
{
    Cell cellOld = getCell(rowIndex, columnIndex);

    Cell cellNew = new Cell
    {
        Value = value,
        DisplayValue = value
    };

    if (true == setCellDisplayValue) {
        cellNew.DisplayValue = value;
    }

    if (null != cellOld)
    {
        cellNew.ColumnId = cellOld.ColumnId;
    }

    var listOfNewCells = new List<Cell>();

    listOfNewCells.Add(cellNew);

    Row rowNew = new Row
    {
        Cells = listOfNewCells
    };

    Row rowOld = sheetAPITest.GetRowByRowNumber(rowIndex);

    if (null != rowOld)
    {
        rowNew.Id = rowOld.Id;
    }

    var listOfNewRows = new List<Row>();

    listOfNewRows.Add(rowNew);

    smartsheetClient.SheetResources.RowResources.UpdateRows(sheetIdAPITest, listOfNewRows);
}
```

I also wrote a helper method getCell.

```
public Cell getCell(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
{
    Row row = sheetAPITest.GetRowByRowNumber(rowIndex);

    if (null == row)
    {
        return null;
    }

    Column column = sheetAPITest.GetColumnByIndex(columnIndex);

    if (null == column)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return row.Cells.First(c => c.ColumnId == column.Id);
}
```

The problem seems to be that sheetAPITest.GetRowByRowNumber(rowIndex) returns null when there is no value in the row. I need the row because i need the row id to create the new row with the content.

What am I missing? Any ideas how i can solve the problem? Maybe there is a better approach? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why the downvote without any comment? I have searched the net and looked into the code of the SDK and the documentation and did not find a way to write to a specific cell given the row index, column index and value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Add Rows](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?csharp#add-rows) method to add the new row and populate one or more cells in the row.

Note that by default, the **Add Rows** method will add the new row(s) to the end of the sheet, but you can change this default behavior by [specifying row location](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?csharp#specify-row-location) for each row.

The following code sample adds 2 new rows to the top of the specified sheet and populates 2 cells within each of those rows:

```
// Specify cell values for first row
Cell[] cellsA = new Cell[] {
  new Cell
  {
    ColumnId = 7960873114331012,
    Value = true
  },
  new Cell
  {
    ColumnId = 642523719853956,
    Value = "New status"
  }
};

// Specify contents of first row
Row rowA = new Row
{
  ToTop = true,
  Cells = cellsA
};

// Specify cell values of second row
Cell[] cellsB = new Cell[] {
  new Cell
  {
    ColumnId = 7960873114331012,
    Value = true
  },
  new Cell
  {
    ColumnId = 642523719853956,
    Value = "New status"
  }
};

// Specify contents of second row
Row rowB = new Row
{
  ToTop = true,
  Cells = cellsB
};

// Add rows to sheet
IList<Row> newRows = smartsheet.SheetResources.RowResources.AddRows(
  2331373580117892,               // long sheetId
  new Row[] { rowA, rowB }        // IEnumerable<Row> rowsToAdd
);
```